# Convert a ~800k adjacency list MySQL table to nested set

Tags: mysql, tree, nested-sets, adjacency-list

I have a very large MySQL table (840000 records) with a `parent_id` column only.
I want to convert it into a nested set design (with `left`, `right` columns).

What is the best way to do that in terms of memory, e.g. not keeping all 800k records in RAM.

I have a copy of the table, so it's ok to lock the whole table/database.

The table is ordered, so `parent_id` < `id`.